# One regex, multiple replacements

Tags: php, regex

OK, that's what I need :

- Get all entries formatted like `%%something%%`, as given by the regex `/%%([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)%%/i`
- Replace all instances with values from a table, given the index `something`.

**E.g.**

Replace `%%something%%` with `$mytable['something']`, etc.

---

If it was a regular replacement, I would definitely go for `preg_replace`, or even create an array of possible replacements... But what if I want to make it a bit more flexible...

Ideally, I'd want something like `preg_replace($regex, $mytable["$1"], $str);`, but obviously it doesn't look ok...

---

How should I go about this?

Comment: You are looking for `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: Though I am not a PHP guy, but you may try adding global hook `g` in your regex, e.g. `/%%([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)%%/gi`

Comment: @Jon Yep, that's what I was looking for. Please, post it as a proper answer and you'll get all the credit you deserve. Thanks a lot, buddy! :-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: No need really. If you want to give credit, just upvote on that other question. Cheers!

Comment: @Jon Na sai kala. (= nobody is gonna understand that. lol)

Comment: If you use the `[A-Za-z0-9-]` class, you don't need to put the i modifier

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Good point. Old habits die hard... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
<?php

$myTable = array(
    'one' => '1!',
    'two' => '2!',
);

$str = '%%one%% %%two%% %%three%%';

$str = preg_replace_callback(
    '@%%(.*?)%%@',
    function ($matches) use ($myTable) {
        if (isset($myTable[$matches[1]]))
            return $myTable[$matches[1]];
        else
            return $matches[0];
    },
    $str
);

echo $str;
```

Result:

```
1! 2! %%three%%
```

if you don't want to tell upper from lower,

```
<?php

$myTable = array(
    'onE' => '1!',
    'Two' => '2!',
);

$str = '%%oNe%% %%twO%% %%three%%';

$str = preg_replace_callback(
    '@%%(.*?)%%@',
    function ($matches) use ($myTable) {
        $flipped = array_flip($myTable);
        foreach ($flipped as $v => $k) {
            if (!strcasecmp($k, $matches[1]))
                return $v;
        }
        return $matches[1];
    },
    $str
);

echo $str;
```